# Get range of values with group by clause in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this in mongodb.

```
{
  "_id": "1235677",
  "name" : "xyz",
  "time" : ISODate(2015-07-20T09:00:00Z)
},
{
  "_id": "1235677",
  "name" : "xyz",
  "time" : ISODate(2015-07-20T11:00:00Z)
},
{
  "_id": "1235677",
  "name" : "abs",
  "time" : ISODate(2015-07-20T11:00:00Z)
}
```

How do i get Max(time) minus Min(time) for ever name in database. Equivalent to this sql query -

```
SELECT name, Max(time)-Min(time) from tablename group by name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) for MongoDB like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$name",
        "minTime": { "$min": "$time" },
        "maxTime": { "$max": "$time" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "duration": { "$subtract": [ "$minTime", "$maxTime" ] }
    }}
])
```

You use the aggregation framework for everything (optimally) that does not involve a basic ( SQL equivalent ) type of statement:

```sql
SELECT something FROM table
```

The operations here are as follows:

- [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/): Is the same as "GROUP BY", where you specify the "key(s)" you want want to aggregate for within the `_id` primary key value. The [**`$min`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) and [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operators are the same as "MIN()" and "MAX()" respectively, in that that act as a functon withing the "grouping" as "accumulators".
- The [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) is an extention of the general syntax in MongoDB terms. This allows you to "manipulate" existing field values ( in this case calculated from `$group` into new values in the document.

  So in here the "calculation" is applied by the [**`$subtract`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) from both values to determine the result.

Though specific examples are not always given, I would strongly recommend looking at the [SQL to MongoDB mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/) section of the core documentation. As well as looking though and learning the [aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) themselves in full.

Answer (score 4):

Please Try the below :

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group:{_id:"$name",maxt: {$max:"$time"}, mint : {$min:"$time"}} },
  { $project: {"_id" : 0 ,"name": "$_id", 
    "time" : {$subtract: ["$mint","$maxt"]}} }
 ]);
```